# Does entrywise bounded positive definite matrix also have bounded inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, inverse, positive-definite

Suppose $A(x)\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a matrix-valued function.

Assume that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $A(x)$ is positive definite, and $A(x)$ is uniformly entrywise bounded (i.e., absolute value of entry) by a constant $C$ independent of $x$.

Is it true that the matrix inversion $(A(x))^{-1}$ is also uniformly entrywise bounded? If not, do we have any counter-example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true even in the case that $n=1$. Consider $A(x) = e^{-|x|}$.

---

The absolute values of the entries of $A^{-1}$ are bounded above by $1/\sigma_\min(A)$. If $A$ is positive definite and symmetric, then its singular values are equal to its eigenvalues.

To see that this is the case, note that $\sigma_\max(A^{-1}) = 1/\sigma_\min(A)$, and for all matrix $M$ and vectors $v$ we have $\|Mv\| \leq \sigma_\max(M) \cdot \|v\|$. If we use $e_j$ to denote the $j$th standard unit vector, then we have
$$
|A^{-1}_{ij}| = |e_i^T A^{-1}e_j| \leq \|e_i\| \cdot \|A^{-1}e_j\| \\
\leq \|e_i\| \cdot \sigma_\max(A^{-1}) \cdot \|e_j\|\\
= 1/\sigma_\min(A).
$$

Comment: aaah, yes. It's trivial to show when $n=1$.

Comment: @NathanExplosion And for general $n$, just take a diagonal matrix with this in all the diagonal entries.

Comment: @Nathan That still won't work. It would be sufficient to have a (global) lower bound on the least singular value of $A$. If $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, it is equivalent to have a lower bound on the smallest eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: So it will be okay if the diagonal entries also have a global positive lower bound?

Comment: @Nathan I'm not sure what you mean. It is not **sufficient** for the diagonal entries to have a global lower bound, if that's what you mean. For instance, take
$$
A(x) = e^{-|x|} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}.
$$

Comment: That's true. Having lower bound on smallest eigenvalue seems to be the best we can do. But how does bounded eigenvalues give entrywise bound?

Comment: @Nathan If $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, then the $i,j$ entry of $A^{-1}$ is at most equal to $[\lambda_{\min}(A)]^{-1}$.

Comment: How is it obvious? Don't we have $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}(A^{-1}) \leq \sqrt{\sum |A_{i,j}^{-1}|^2}$?

Comment: @Nathan It's not obvious. I'll add a proof

Comment: @NathanExplosion See my latest edit.

Comment: Now it's clear, much appreciated!